# Server error 500 on sending email on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django project. The user fills the form and then I receive a notification about new order.  Localy, on my computer everything is ok. I deploy my application on Heroku and on the site I cannot send emails. I receive error 500.

This is my code:

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='sitename'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import OrderForm


def contact(request):
    company='no company'

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form=OrderForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            company=form.cleaned_data['company']

            try:
                msg_plain = render_to_string('../templates/publicity_agency/email.txt', {'company':company})
                msg_html = render_to_string('../templates/publicity_agency/email.html', {'company':company})
                msg_plain_client = render_to_string('../templates/publicity_agency/email_client.txt')
                msg_html_client = render_to_string('../templates/publicity_agency/email_client.html')
                send_mail('New order',msg_plain,'Notification <myemail@gmail.com>', ['myemail@gmail.com'], html_message=msg_html)
                send_mail('Order',msg_plain_client,'Order <myemail@gmail.com>', [email], html_message=msg_html_client)
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')
            return redirect('contact')
    else:
        form=OrderForm()

    return render(request, 'publicity_agency/contacts.html', {'company':company})
```

Comment: what is the 500 error message? any logs?

Comment: @Elisha I have only "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" . On heroku in application logs "at=info method=POST path="/contact/" host=mysite.herokuapp.com request_id=d062d5a7-388f-4e1f-8b57-6a28fadf9e95 fwd="178.145.62.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=542ms status=500 bytes=253"

Comment: there is not enough information here, you can try the following:   
1. try to deploy your app in debug mode and get more info   
2. catch Exception (not only BadHeaderError) and print it   
3. add the POST data to the question, the request that was sent to the server

Comment: Before deploying, set `settings.DEBUG`= True. Then, try to send an email and see the logs.

Comment: Not what you are asking (and I don't think it affects the issue), but `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` must be an email address. Now, in what you are asking; whenever there's a 500 error, Django emails the admins. But given that there's a problem in emailing, it might not be able to do so. So if possible set `DEBUG = True`, otherwise try printing the exception as Elisha suggested.